# How view owner of file on Windows XP with command line tools

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I use

```
cmd# dir uuid.vbs /q /s
15.08.2011  16:52                83 HOST\user           uuid.vbs
```

but this not work for Windows shares which mounted by:

```
cmd# net use t: \\192.168.1.44\distr
```

It take output like:

```
cmd# dir wget.later /q /s
15.08.2011  09:16                66 ...                 wget.later
```

Also when in Explorer check Properties ==> Security you can see list of users/groups that have some permition for this file.

How can I list owner or users/groups which have permition on file from command line? May be VB/JS-scrips allow this (as come starting from Win2000)?

Answer (score 3):

Use `cacls filename`. It will give the access information of the file.

Comment: For shares it writes that domain not found for some ... users. With Properties ==> Security you can see list of users/groups that have some permition for this file.

Comment: I echo @gavenkoa, `cacls` (and `icacls`) doesn't reliably report owner on network shares. As near as I can tell from the machines I have access to: a) On Windows Server 2003 `cacls` says `Everyone:F`, `dir /q` says `BUILTIN\Administrators` and Windows Explorer says `Administrators (SERVERNAME\Administrators)`; b) on a samba server (a QNAP NAS device)  `cacls reports ``<Account Domain not found>F`, `dir /q` says either `...` or `DOMAIN\username` for different files (haven't figured out why/how), and Windows Explorer says `Username (SERVERNAME\username` or `Full.Name (username@our.domain.org)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that your machine is not part of a domain and you are trying to list security permissions for a network share that is.

My machine at work is not part of the domain and `dir /q` will not list ownership correctly for files in a network share.  File owners show up as "...".  I solved this problem by remote desktop to a machine that is part of the domain and then running a cmd from there.

You can also start a remote `cmd` shell using `psexec \\server cmd`.